# Use JSON with JAVA NIO

Tags: java, json, nio

i have a program that use json file. i write a jsonobject in a file and then i read from the file and i parse it.

for write on the file i use:

```
File file=new File(nomeFile);


        try {

            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.write(obj.toJSONString());
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and for read:

```
try {
            FileReader f=new FileReader(file);

            obj =parser.parse(f);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

//and i do the get
```

now i have to change this code for use NIO instead of IO

is it possible?
how can i do it?
thanks

Comment: `File`, `FileWriter`, and `FileReader` should be compatible with Java NIO. What NIO specific classes and methods do you want to use? Don't you want to read/write a file?

Comment: `File.createNewFile()` is completely pointless here, or worse. `new FileWriter(...)` already does that, and you are now forcing it to delete the file you just created as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article [how to read with NIO](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-nio-read-file-example/) and [how to write with NIO](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/file-nio/java-nio-write-file-example/)

Quick try:

For write :

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/question.txt");

String question = "To be or not to be?";

Files.write(path, question.getBytes());
```

For read:

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/shakespeare.txt");

try {

  Files.lines(path).forEach(System.out::println);//print each line

} catch (IOException ex) {

  ex.printStackTrace();//handle exception here

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**WRITE:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(CLI_FILES_DIR + File.separator + "applications" + File.separator + "yourFile.json")) {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(gson.toJson(yourObject));
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("IOException: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

**READ:**

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CLI_FILES_DIR + File.separator + "applications" + File.separator + "yourFile.json"))) {
    YourObject yourObject = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, YourObject.class);
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("IOException: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

You can find a fully sample [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/cli/NoraUiCommandLineInterface.java)

Comment: but bufferedReader is in IO not in NIO. I can't use IO :( this is the problem

Comment: @Alice You can't use `java.io` why? It's perfectly normal to use it for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Alice I have same question:  You can't use java.io why?

Comment: is the request of my exercise